# CDF of middle of $3$ random variables

Tags: statistics, order-statistics

Let the independent random variables $X_1$, $X_2$, $X_3$ have the same cdf $F(X).$
Let $Y$ be the middle value (second largest) of $X_1$, $X_2$, $X_3$. Determine the cdf of  $Y$. (Hint: use a Binomial distribution).

My approach is that this is a binomial distribution where I am trying to calculate the probability that $2$ of that random variables are less than or equal to some number $x$ and one is of the random variables is larger. Is this the right approach?

Answer (score 1):

That is correct.
$$
F_{\text{middle}} (x) = \Pr(\text{the middle one}\le x) = \Pr(\text{number of successes}\ge 2)
$$
where "success" on the $i$th trial means $X_i\le x$, and that has a probability that depends on $x$.